# JQuery. CheckBoxes in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.addEventListener("click", function (){
        $('.checkbox').each(function(){
            if ($(this).prop("checked"))
            {
                window.open("[@spring.url "/visit/publicate?id=" + item.visit.id/]");
                visit_id="${item.id}";
            }
        });
    }, false);
</script>
```

I have a big table. Each lane contains checkbox and some URL(each lane contains different URL). If checkbox in some lane has a value "checked", browser should open URL from this lane. My script always return me URL from the first lane of the table. why?

Comment: unreadable, sorry. Can you explain in other words?

Comment: add a fiddle please, to understand what you are trying to say!

Comment: Try to explain a bit clear about you problem

Comment: What is publicate with checkboxes?

Comment: Edited, may be now it is better

Comment: `Id` should be unique in the DOM, if you have multiple elements with the same `id` than the first one is returned by `getElementById`

Comment: He has a table with multiple rows. Each row has a checkbox and an URL. He loops through the rows seeking which checkboxes are checked. If a checkbox is checked he want to open the URL existing in that row. It always opens the first row for him and I think this is because the script never finishes because he goes to first window.open on first checked checkbox.

Comment: @Piwwoli Sounds more like a 'She' instead of a 'He' to me :)

Comment: @tiberiu.corbu Heh, well, I wouldn't know as a Nordic person. Her name is too exotic for me. :P

Comment: Piwwoli is absolutely right

Comment: Another note ... the concatenation here : `window.open("[@spring.url "/visit/publicate?id=" + item.visit.id/]");` is wrong

Comment: @IlyaBeleychev you are saying his answer is right and working fine? or just for the discussion of He & Shee

Comment: He understood my problem, but didn't help

Comment: Atleast add your HTML(minimum), so that we can get how are URLs assigned.

Comment: I passed the code in jsbin and it cries for corrections :
Line 6: Expected ':' and instead saw ')'.
Line 6: Expected an identifier and instead saw ';'.
Line 7: Expected ')' and instead saw 'visit_id'.
Line 7: Bad assignment.
Line 7: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

Comment: My suggestion is to Edit this bin http://jsbin.com/kimih/1/edit or create another from scratch for a simulation ... My hunch is that your problem comes form the `id` of your DOM elements but I cannot take a statement for that unless I have all the Variables.